# React Native: Passing 2 parameter to onPress event

Tags: javascript, events, react-native, event-handling

I need to pass two parameter to my handler function, but i can't find nowhere the right sintax, someone can help me?

```
MyHandler = (e) => {
  var Var_1 = e;
  var Var_2 = second_parameter;
}

render() {
  return (
     <Button onPress={(e) => this.MyHandler(e)} title="1">
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the second parameter and how do you obtain it before calling `MyHandler`?

Comment: I have 5 button that pass as "e" parameter 1 to 5 numbers, but i have to repeat this 5 button N times, so i need a loop and i have to pass in the loop the index of the iteration.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to pass `(e, i)` as the second parameter and into your handler.

Comment: It's run i don't understand why it's does't work before!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
MyHandler = (e, second_parameter) => {
  var Var_1 = e;
  var Var_2 = second_parameter;
}

render() {
  return (
     <Button onPress={(e) => this.MyHandler(e, your_second_parameter)} title="1">
  );
}
```